# Unir dos dt a traves de campo en comun en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

tengo dos *datatable* los cuales los creo así:

```
        DataTable dtSQL = new DataTable("Table1");
        DataTable dtOracle = new DataTable("Table2");

        dtSQL.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TICKET"));
        dtSQL.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS"));
        dtSQL.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RAZON_SOCIAL"));
        dtSQL.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID_OP"));
    dtSQL.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(["SEQ_FOLIO"]));   


        dtOracle.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SEQ_FOLIO"));
        dtOracle.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IMPORTE"));
        dtOracle.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DICTAMEN"));
        dtOracle.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("COMENTARIO"));

        ds.Tables.Add(dtSQL);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtOracle);
```

El metodo lo que hace es unir los dos dt de esta forma (TICKET,STATUS,RAZON_SOCIAL,ID_OP,SEQ_FOLIO,IMPORTE,DICTAMEN,COMENTARIO) y
lo que quiero hacer es que del dtSQL si el campo `SEQ_FOLIO` es igual al del dtOracle se unen en un row, si no son iguales entonces los campos del dtOracle deberian estar en blanco, ya que ese dt puede o no contenertener informacion, este es mi metodo que uso pero hasta el momento no me une ningún registro solo me muestra los registros del dtSQL que es el que siempre trae información

```
public static DataTable Union(DataTable First, DataTable Second)

    {

        //Result table

        DataTable table = new DataTable("Union");

        //Build new columns

        DataColumn[] newcolumns = new DataColumn[First.Columns.Count + Second.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < First.Columns.Count; i++)

        {

            newcolumns[i] = new DataColumn(First.Columns[i].ColumnName, First.Columns[i].DataType);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Second.Columns.Count; i++)

        {
            if (Second.Columns[i].ColumnName == "SEQ_FOLIO")
                newcolumns[First.Columns.Count + i] = new DataColumn(Second.Columns[i].ColumnName + i, Second.Columns[i].DataType);
            else
                newcolumns[First.Columns.Count + i] = new DataColumn(Second.Columns[i].ColumnName, Second.Columns[i].DataType);

        }

        //add new columns to result table

        table.Columns.AddRange(newcolumns);

        //Load data from first table
        DataRow[] drs = null;
        List<object> lista = new List<object>();
        foreach (DataRow row in First.Rows)
        {
            lista.Clear();
            drs = Second.Select("SEQ_FOLIO='" + row["SEQ_FOLIO"].ToString() + "'");

            if (drs.Length == 1)
            {
                lista.AddRange(row.ItemArray);
                lista.AddRange(drs[0].ItemArray);
                table.Rows.Add(lista.ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                lista.AddRange(row.ItemArray);
                lista.AddRange(new object[Second.Columns.Count]);
                table.Rows.Add(lista.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return table;

    }
```

Comment: Por definición, las llaves primarias deben ser únicas. Si quieres permitir duplicados, entonces no pongas esa columna sola como llave primaria, o no la pongas para nada.

Comment: @jachguate pero si quito la llave primaria ya no me une los registros de la tabla A con la B, tendria que cambiar algo en el metodo que une los datatable?

Comment: Entonces no he entendido lo que quieres lograr. Re-lee tu pregunta y agrega más información sobre el resultado que esperas.

Comment: ¿Qué te impide unir los campos de ambas tablas usando una `SELECT` en lugar de unirlos en el programa?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster que tengo una tabla en SQL y la otra en Oracle, y no tengo privilegios para poder crear un DBLink por ejemplo para poder hacer una query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se agrega nueva columna `TICKET` al `dtOracle` y en la funcion `SELECT` se agrega otra condición para que pudieran coincidir por `SEQ_FOLIO` y `TICKET`

```
drs = Second.Select("SEQ_FOLIO='" + row["SEQ_FOLIO"].ToString() + "'AND TICKET='" + row["TICKET"].ToString() + "'";);
```